# How to populate an array in a for loop in batch file?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, batch-file

Here is what I have right now:

```
set /A  i=0
for /D %%d in (*.*) do (
set directory[!i!]=%%d
 set /A i=i+1
)
```

I was trying to search for all the folders in current directory and put their names in an array called `directory`. However, the directory array is always empty after execution. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you remember to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of the script?

Comment: That works, thank you so much. I'll just have to use `endlocal` afterwards so that I can change the directory.